# Python 2.5 module allowing implementation of javascript under windows

Tags: javascript, python, windows

hi im looking for some modules for python 2.5 whitch allows to run and executes javascript ... any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pyv8](http://code.google.com/p/pyv8/) definitely supports Windows, but I'm not sure that it supports Python 2.5 out of the box (the pre-built binary packages definitely require Python 2.6; I think that you can build from sources with 2.5, but you might need to tweak said sources for the purpose, and I think you will also need a suitable C compiler, compatible with the one used to build your 2.5 [[mingw may help, perhaps with more tweaks]]).

If you could upgrade your Python to 2.6 that would simplify things a lot... what's keeping you blocked to 2.5?

Answer (score 0):

[python-spidermonkey](http://code.google.com/p/python-spidermonkey/)

> This Python module allows for the implementation of Javascript?
>   classes, objects and functions in Python, as well as the evaluation
>   and calling of Javascript scripts and functions. It borrows heavily
>   from Claes Jacobssen's Javascript Perl module, which in turn is based
>   on Mozilla's PerlConnect Perl binding.

Comment: yeah but only in version 0.5 ... v0.9 cant be run under win